# Add animation to map components in React

Tags: reactjs, react-animated

So i take my data from sanity then map them and then render them as components

my code is

```
function Projects() {

   return <ProjectList projects={projectData} />;
}

export default Projects;
```

```
import ProjectItem from "./ProjectItem";

function ProjectList(props) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.projects.map((project) => (
        <ProjectItem
          key={project.id}
          id={project.id}
          title={project.title}
          description={project.desc}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}

export default ProjectList;
```

```
  Card,
  Project,
  ProjectTitle,
  ProjectDesc,
  ProjectUrl,
  BtnWrap,
} from "./ProjecItemElements";

function ProjectItem(props) {
  return (
    <Project>
      <Card>
        <ProjectTitle>{props.title}</ProjectTitle>
        <ProjectDesc>{props.description}</ProjectDesc>
        <BtnWrap>
          <ProjectUrl>Test</ProjectUrl>
        </BtnWrap>
      </Card>
    </Project>
  );
}

export default ProjectItem;
```

Card,  Project,  ProjectTitle,  ProjectDesc,  ProjectUrl,  BtnWrap, are custom components so i can customize them using that

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Card = styled.div`
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
`;

export const Project = styled.li`
  margin: 1rem 0;
  padding: 1rem;
`;

export const ProjectTitle = styled.h3`
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: #2c292b;
`;

export const ProjectDesc = styled.p`
  color: black;
`;

export const BtnWrap = styled.div`
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1.5rem 1.5rem 0;
`;

export const ProjectUrl = styled.button`
  text-decoration: none;
  color: initial;
`;
```

what i want is to animate the components in the ul

```
{props.projects.map((project) => (
        <ProjectItem
          key={project.id}
          id={project.id}
          title={project.title}
          description={project.desc}
        />
```

so they will come from the bottom to top with a delay when the page 'loads'
(its not really load because React)

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: I would recommend http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group for what you've described

Comment: i can't create the animation